# command not found error on Mac when running mfp from command line

Tags: mobilefirst-cli

I am getting `mfp: command not found` error on Mac. I obviously have installed `mobilefirst-cli` using `npm install -g path-to-cli-.tgz-file`

How can I check/verify if `mobilefirst-cli` is successfully installed on Mac? I tried to run `mfp` but got the error "Command not found".

Comment: what version of MFP are you trying to install?

Comment: where to check it? I installed it from instructions posted here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/ There is no mention of version here

Comment: This is really stupid but maybe you need to open a new terminal window...this has tripped me up a few times installing other things...

Comment: @MBillau Yes, I tried it by opening new Terminal Windows, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MobileFirst 8.0 https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/ then the executable will be `mfpdev`

Comment: yes it was MobileFirst 8.0 and I could run mfpdev executable, but in all docs it is mentioned as mfp.

Comment: @AADTechnical glad it worked, we will get the doc fixed

Answer (score 0):

Specify PATH in zshrc or bashrc. *Command: gedit ~/.zshrc* 
Also source it. *Command: source ~/.zshrc*
Once that is done. Restart terminal and you should be able to access mfp commands in cli.